# Populate parent entry id nested form by gravity form

Tags: forms, gravity

[This code](https://github.com/gravitywiz/snippet-library/blob/master/gp-nested-forms/gpnf-populate-parent-entry-id.php), created by the good gravity wiz team, does not work for me.
Does it need special customization or should a part of it be changed?
I am not a programmer